# SSMS query-window connection options are all disabled after a network disconnect, can't be enabled after that is corrected

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I leave a connected SSMS tab open (version 18.2), and the database disconnects (e.g. server restart, network change, etc.), then in both in the Query menu/Connection sub-menu, and directly in a tab's connection property, "Connect", "Disconnect", "Disconnect All Queries", and "Change Connection" are all grayed out. Even when I establish a connection, such as in a new query tab, these are never re-enabled again. Currently, my workaround is just to create a new query tab- which always works and is connected - and then copy the contents of the now-orphaned tab to the new tab, and toss out the old tab.

This is annoying, and I may have a number of such tabs needing this handling. This worked fine for the last 18 months, until upgrading to SSMS 18. Is there any way to "wake up" SSMS tabs?

Please, no off-topic questions about "why are you doing that". The topic is this technical issue with SSMS.

Comment: I have the same issue in version 18.9.2... I always restart SSMS, then it goes back to normal and those options are enabled. I also use Sql Prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but no one answered.

In the new query window run, SQL Server will reconnect with last session.
SELECT 1